# Android BottomNavBar Item Titles Dissappear After Adding New Item

Tags: android, android-theme, bottomnavigationview, android-color

I'm trying to add a new item to the bottom navigation bar of one of my apps, but for some reason when i add the XML for the new item the titles of all *un-clicked* items dissapear.

Here is the XML before adding the new item

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_lessons"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_lessons"
    android:title="@string/lessons" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_simulator"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_simulator"
    android:title="@string/simulator" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_quiz"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_quiz"
    android:title="@string/quiz" />
```

this looks like this
[image]

but after adding the new item to the XML

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_lessons"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_lessons"
    android:title="@string/lessons" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_simulator"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_simulator"
    android:title="@string/simulator" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_quiz"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_quiz"
    android:title="@string/quiz" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_settings"
    android:title="@string/settings" />
```

The bottom nav bar looks like this
[image]

I am using some custom colors & styles but i don't change anything in those before & after adding a new item. im going to share my style & colors anyway though

This is the style

```
 <style name="ThemeOverlay.Custom.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/bottom_nav_light</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">@color/bottom_nav_light</item>
    <item name="itemBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

And here is the color

```
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#000000" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:color="#595959"/>
```

I tries changing the title color programmatically but couldn't get anywhere, does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using Material or Material3? The [Material specs](https://m2.material.io/components/bottom-navigation#anatomy) do specifically call out in the 'Representing destinations' section how the number of icons affect whether labels are shown.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, i would have never found this out otherwise!